# Python: Global object lock in multiprocessing

Tags: python, multiprocessing, mutex, python-multiprocessing

Consider running multiprocessing on a huge data, made of elements of some class object.
Data is in memory as a global variable and each function to run in parallel takes data index as argument, accesses the global data object, reads the text in this index, runs computation and returns a result without modifying the global object.

```
import concurrent

import numpy as np

data_size = 1_000_000

class DataClass:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

def process_text(dataset_idx):
    return dataset[dataset_idx].text.lower()

dataset = [DataClass('SOME TEXT') for _ in range(data_size)]
dataset_indices_to_process = range(data_size)

results = []
with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
    for result in executor.map(process_text, dataset_indices_to_process ):
        results.append(result)
```

Does this bring about any overhead due to the global object being locked during read process of one of the subprocesses?
What is the optimal way to parallelize such a read-only access to global data?

Comment: Why would a lock be needed, if the object is read-only?  Also, I see no lock in your code.  More important, however, is that sharing state among Processes is not always straightforward.  See the Programming Guidelines for the multiprocessing module in the standard docs.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are only reading data, you *could* get away with the following code. But each process in the pool will have its own copy of the `dataset` list. This is true even if your platform uses the *fork* method of creating new processes where variables are inherited because each process will be incrementing a reference count for the inherited list, which will cause a new copy to be made:

```py
data_size = 1_000_000

class DataClass:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

def process_text(dataset_idx):
    return dataset[dataset_idx].text.lower()

# We don't need a list comprehension:
dataset = [DataClass('SOME TEXT')] * data_size

# Required if the platform is Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import concurrent.futures # Not: import concurrent

    dataset_indices_to_process = range(data_size)

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        # No need to explicitly loop:
        results = list(executor.map(process_text, dataset_indices_to_process))
```

Ideally you would have a single copy of the list of strings created in shared memory by the main process. Unfortunately, a string reference, unlike for example an integer, contained within the list would not be valid in other processes. The best you can do, I believe, is to use a *managed* list. Be aware that each operation on the list is akin to a remote method call to another process and thus performs more slowly compared with access to a "regular" dictionary:

```py
class DataClass:
    def __init__(self, text):
        self.text = text

def initialize_pool_processes(arr):
    global dataset
    dataset = arr

def process_text(dataset_idx):
    return dataset[dataset_idx].text.lower()

# Required if the platform is Windows:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    import concurrent.futures # Not: import concurrent
    from multiprocessing import Manager

    data_size = 1_000_000
    dataset_indices_to_process = range(data_size)
    dataset = Manager().list([DataClass('SOME TEXT')] * data_size)

    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(initializer=initialize_pool_processes, initargs=(dataset,)) as executor:
        # No need to explicitly loop:
        results = list(executor.map(process_text, dataset_indices_to_process))
```